# Inequality with Absolute Values

Tags: inequality

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive real numbers. If $a + b + c \le 4$ and $4 \le ab + bc + ac$, then show that at least two of the following inequalities $|a−b| \le 2$, $|b−c| \le 2$, $|c−a| \le 2$ are true.

Comment: $$ \implies (a+b+c)^2 \leq 16$$
$$ \implies (a^2+b^2+c^2)+2(ab+bc+ca) \leq 16$$
$$ \implies (a^2+b^2+c^2) \leq 8$$
$$ \implies 2(a^2+b^2+c^2) \leq 16$$
$$ \implies 2(a^2+b^2+c^2)-2(ab+bc+ca) \leq 16-2(ab+bc+ca)$$
$$ \implies (a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 \leq 8$$
Do you have any idea after this? Actual I am not able to see the next the step.

Answer (score 1):

At least two of them are no greater than $2$ means that at most one of them is greater than $2$. This we can prove by contradiction using Rajada's work above: if two or more are greater than $2$, then squaring those that are greater than $2$ we get the square is greater than $4$, and two of them greater than $4$ so the sum is more than $8$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be the smallest of them.
Let's assume that both $b$ and $c$ are greater than $a$ by a margin greater than 2.

So, $b=a+2+\alpha$ and $c=a+2+\beta$

Where $\alpha, \beta \ge 0$

So, $a+b+c\le4$ implies $3a+\alpha+\beta\le0$ which is not possible because $a$ is given to be positive and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are nonnegative.

Thus, the assumption that two of the three numbers exceed the smallest of them by at least a margin of 2 must be false.

Thus, at least two of the inequalities in the question have to be true.

Comment: I am in a bit of a fix because why the second given condition is required. Is there a flaw in my reasoning?